Why the principle of duality in Boolean Algebra is right?
In class, my teacher explained the knowledge of digital circuit logic.He explained what the $principle\ of \ duality$ is, but he didn't explain the proof, and I was very interested in the proof.
$principle\ of \ duality:$
Every algebraic identity of Boolean algebra remains equal if the operations(+) and ($\cdot$), and the 0 and 1 are interchanged throughout.
Symbol "+"means "∨", and $\cdot$ means "∧",$\bar A$ means ¬ A.
For example, let $F = AB+\bar A C + BC, G=AB+\bar A C$ ,
we know that $F = G$ is right.
According to $principle\ of \ duality$ ,we have following algebraic identity:
$(A+B)(\bar A + C)(B+C)=(A+B)(\bar A + C)$
I read the following article which is similar but different to my question,  and find "structural induction" .It proved $\bar F$ equals to "F  by replacing all occurrences of $\cdot$ by$+$ ,$+$ by $\cdot$, 1 by 0, 0 by 1 and all variables by their negations"
Proof of Principle of Duality: Show that $φ$' is logically equivalent to $¬φ$
So how to prove $principle\ of \ duality$? Can structural induction prove it?

One sort of cheating way to prove this is to note that Boolean algebras really just are partial orders satisfying some additional conditions. Reversing the order produces another Boolean algebra, and reversing the orders corresponds to swapping $\vee$ and $\wedge$, and $0$ and $1$.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Can you prove it or give me a hint?

@MauroALLEGRANZA The "Principle of Duality" in the link is different from
Principle of Duality under this question.In this question, Principle of Duality don't have changed variables to their negation and it should prove a algebraic identity.

@DavidGao thanks.But I know very little about partial older sets.Is there a proof method using structural induction just like the proof in the link.Because I think the two questions are similar.

@billwang The proof you linked can be easily adapted to Boolean algebras, if you insist on using induction. It's just more complicated than necessary to me. If you want to avoid partial orders, you can still use my "sort of cheating" method - just note that the axioms of Boolean algebras are invariant under swapping $\vee$ and $\wedge$, and $0$ and $1$. So, if you perform those swaps, you get another Boolean algebra. Hence, the swapped Boolean algebra must satisfy the given identities as well - but that just means the swapped identities still hold for all Boolean algebras.

I gave the accepted Answer in the link you included in your question that showed that $\phi ' \Leftrightarrow \neg \phi$ where $\phi '$ is obtained from $\phi$ by replacing all operators by their duals and all variables by their negations.  You are right that this is not the same as showing the actual dual principle, but it gets you pretty close: define $\phi^D$ to be the dual statement of $\phi$, i.e. just replace the operators by their duals, but leave variables alone. And define $\phi^*$ to be the statement that leaves the operators alone, but replaces all variables with their negations.

It is easy to see that $\phi' = (\phi^)^D$, and given that I showed that $\phi' \Leftrightarrow \neg \phi$, you thus get that $\phi \Leftrightarrow \neg \phi' = \neg (\phi^)^D$. (will continue soon .. sorry just have to do something ...)

Also note that variables in any equivalence can stand for any statement (this is called the Substitution or Replacement Principle and is something we use intuitively, e.g. given that $A \land B \Leftrightarrow B \land A)$, you also have that $(C \to D) \land \neg \neg F \Leftrightarrow \neg \neg F \land (C \to D)$. So in particular you can replace every variable by its negation and retain equivalence, which means that if $\phi \Leftrightarrow \psi$, then $\phi^* \Leftrightarrow \psi^$. Oh, and I should also quickly point out that $\neg (\phi)^ = (\neg \phi)^*$, which is trivial to see.

OK, and now we can get the Duality Principle: if $\phi \Leftrightarrow \psi$, then $\phi^D \Leftrightarrow (\neg (\phi^)^D)^D =  ((\neg \phi^)^D)^D = (\neg \phi)^* = \neg (\phi)^* \Leftrightarrow \neg (\psi)^* = (\neg \psi)^* =  ((\neg \psi^)^D)^D = (\neg (\phi^)^D)^D \Leftrightarrow \psi^D$

@Bram28 Great!That's the answer I was looking for. I've thought about this before with the truth table. Because ′⇔‘, For a row in ' truth table (which is called A) and the row that inverts all the 01's of that row (which is called B), ^ is swapping the assignments of the two rows, A and B, but leaves the results alone.So  and  have the same truth table.

@billwang You're welcome!  Yes, thinking about it in terms of a truth-table makes it intuitively clear. The mathematical proof like I just did is a little more involved and abstract.
